# R predict() dependent variable Y=f(X) using arbitrary coefficients

Tags: r, glm, predict

I am running a logistic regression of the following form in R:

`results<-glm(Y~X,family=binomial(link='logit'))` from which I derive the estimated coefficients and the fitted observations [image: \hat{Y}=f(X;\hat{\beta})].

I am wondering if it is possible to calculate a different [image: \widetilde{Y}] using some other arbitrary fixed value [image: \widetilde{\beta}].

Please note that I have already tried to change the estimated coefficients `results$cofficients<-c(0.9,1.2)` (here 0.9 and 1.2 are just examples) and use the function `predict(results,type="response")` although it did not work as there was no difference between the fitted values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the coefficients should do it.  However, if you're predicting with the original data by just relying on the predict function using your original data if not passed any additional data to predict (i.e. not using `newdata=something`) it uses the fitted values from the model object directly.

You can bypass this by telling it to use `newdata=your_original_data` in your call to predict.

An example

```
> dat <- mtcars[1:5,]
> results <- glm(vs ~ mpg, data = dat, family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
> predict(results)
        Mazda RX4     Mazda RX4 Wag        Datsun 710    Hornet 4 Drive Hornet Sportabout 
        -23.66411         -23.66411         186.49174          23.03719        -292.19658 
> coefficients(results)
(Intercept)         mpg 
 -2475.4823    116.7532 
> results$coefficients[1] <- 0
> predict(results) # uses original fitted values
        Mazda RX4     Mazda RX4 Wag        Datsun 710    Hornet 4 Drive Hornet Sportabout 
        -23.66411         -23.66411         186.49174          23.03719        -292.19658 
> predict(results, newdata = dat)
        Mazda RX4     Mazda RX4 Wag        Datsun 710    Hornet 4 Drive Hornet Sportabout 
         2451.818          2451.818          2661.974          2498.519          2183.286
```

Comment: Just to make it clear  and consistent with the question above you propose `newdata=X` ?

Comment: @Whitebeard13 Sure. I was just assuming Y and X were placeholders for the actual variable names and you were using a `data` parameter as well.

Comment: It indeed works. The only thing that should be changed in your example code (please let me know if I am wrong) is: `predict(results, newdata = dat)` should become `predict(results, newdata = dat,type="response")`

Comment: @Whitebeard13 Sure.  Honestly it's not that important to the mechanics of the actual question/answer so I didn't bother.

Comment: @Whitebeard13 I'm rejecting the edit because the code wouldn't actually match the output at that point.  If you want to make your changes (and make them to all calls to predict) that's fine but update the output as well.